# When using sendfile in express as part of a route to a static html file, the associated .js and .css files are downloaded, but aren't applied.

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, express

I have a simple local server running on a default express setup.

I have an app.js and index.js file for routing.

in the app.js is all the standard stuff express puts in, including the line for static files:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

in the index.js file, I have the route:

```
 router.get('/', function(req, res) {
        res.sendfile('public/staticHTMLfile.html');
    });
```

in the public folder, I have the .js and .css files, with their paths referenced properly in the static html file.

When I access localhost:3000/ in a browser, the html loads properly, and I see from my npm command prompt that the associated js file and css files have been accessed:

```
GET /public/jsFile.js 404 424ms - 1.34kb
GET /public/cssFile.css 404 27ms - 1.34kb
```

Any idea why they aren't being applied to the html? I have double checked the script and link tags for the correct path.

Let me know if you need more information.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

The `404` that you see in the line `GET /public/jsFile.js` means that the file cannot be found. They are not being downloaded, they are being requested but very likely to the wrong path.

Given that the path says `public/jsFile.js` I believe this is because you included "public" in the path. Remove this. The path to the JS and CSS files in your HTML should be "/jsFile.js" and "/cssFile.css"

As a test, point your browser to `/public/jsFile.js` and you should get an error but pointing your browser to `/jsFile.js` should work.